# C and _Thread_local

Tags: c

I read that GCC 4.9 has support for `_Thread_local`.

[Here](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.9/changes.html) is said:

> ISO C11 thread-local storage (_Thread_local, similar to GNU C
>   __thread) is now supported.

However I installed on Fedora 21 GCC 4.9.1-11 but the include file `threads.h` is not present.

Any idea?

Does anyone know if there is a compiler with this support?

Comment: No, this is not a duplicate because I'm asking if someone has installed GCC 4.9 and tried to use _Thread_local.

Comment: How do you compile your program? Show the compilation command. You need to try with `gcc -std=c11 -Wall -g`

Comment: You don't need to include "threads.h" to use _Thread_local.

Comment: Ok, to use _Thread_local I don't need to include threads.h. That include file is only necessary to use functions to manage threads and also to use the macro thread_local. @Basile Starynkevitch, yes your compilation flags are also necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_Thread_local` should work fine, but it's not very useful, except as a way of making your code thread-safe for somebody else using it with threads, unless you have a way to make threads. The C11 threads API would be provided by libc, not the compiler,  and glibc does not support it yet. You can of course use the POSIX threads API.